# Run pre call test demo into Iframe

Tags: opentok, tokbox

How Could I run pre-call test demo of tokbox into my iframe, Here is the link of tokbox `https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/precall/results`, Or Where could I get the full sample code of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

You can utilize the [opentok-network-test-js](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test-js) library to build the pre-call testing into your own application.